# LoopingSelector does not show?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I got the following xaml:

```
           <controls:PanoramaItem Header="overview">

                <Grid>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <toolkit:LoopingSelector Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemMargin="5" Width="160"  ItemSize="160,105" >
                        <toolkit:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Numbers}" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    </toolkit:LoopingSelector>

                </Grid>

            </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

where Numbers looks like this:

```
this.Numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };

public List<int> Numbers { get; private set; }
```

The thing builds and runs, but the loopingselector does not seem to visible... does anyone know why I cant see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly** you need to define the Numbers collection as a public property

```
public List<int> Numbers
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

and set the value of this property in the constructor of your class (or via another method)

```
Numbers = new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
```

**Secondly** you need to bind the Numbers collection to the `DataSource` property on the LoopingSelector rather than to the TextBlock. The DataContext for the TextBlock is then a single integer(item) in your collection.

```
<toolkit:LoopingSelector Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemMargin="5" Width="160"  ItemSize="160,105" DataSource="{Binding Numbers}">
     <toolkit:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
              </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
      </toolkit:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
 </toolkit:LoopingSelector>
```

Comment: Did you update the Xaml as well? Just wanted to double check as you've only updated the C# code in your post

Comment: is your datacontext set properly?

Comment: @pivotnig: Good point, Jason54 where is the Numbers property defined? are you using a view model or is this in the code behind?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Numbers` List has to be public and a property, in order for databinding to work.